# Help identifying component values, same codes different sizes

Tags: esp32

this is a ESP32 dev kit board, I'm confused about the tantalum capacitor, I can read 106C on both of them which are likely to be 10uF and 16V however their sizes are different. Are those actually the same capacity and voltage rating?

[image]

I've looked a few schematics and they all say 10uF on both sides

My best two guesses are

1. Different ESR o other parameter
2. These things are sometimes not highest quality, so they my be trying to fool somebody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [AVX](http://datasheets.avx.com/TAJ.pdf) catalog, there are three sizes of 10uF/16V capacitors available (EIA imperial 1206/1210/2312), and the main differences are the ESR and the ripple current vs. temperature ratings.